# Missing AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml when building with buildozer in VM

Tags: android, python, linux, kivy, buildozer

I am getting an error when I try to build an Android app with buildozer in VM provided by Kivy. I have updated the buildozer and I have run `buildozer init` in the terminal. I do *not* run this in shared folder. I am getting this error:

```
Compiling 

/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kopeckova/private/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 150, in wrapper_func
    func(self, args)
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 754, in apk
    build_args = build.parse_args(args.unknown_args)
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kopeckova/build.py", line 577, in parse_args
    make_package(args)
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kopeckova/build.py", line 365, in make_package
    url_scheme=url_scheme)
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kopeckova/build.py", line 76, in render
    template = environment.get_template(template)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name kopeckova --name Kopeckova --version 1.0 --package org.test.kopeckova --android_api 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/app --presplash /home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/icon.png --icon /home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/icon.png --orientation sensor --intent-filters /home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/sf_kopec/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

There are lot of things going before this error is shown but nothing of it are errors.

There were two other errors before about missing default kivy app icon and spash image which I have solved by adding an image and editing the `buildozer.spec` file. I did not change anything else in the spec file excluding `title`, `package.name` and `version`. I guess it's because of missing default templates or something. Please help :)

Comment: Try building with `buildozer android_new debug`

Comment: Well, it tells me that it was replaced with `android`.

Comment: I would prefer an answer where to get the template or install all the default files.

Comment: Did a successful build for Hello World on the Kivy VM without any fix and changing the buildozer.spec. The Kivy VM is using Xubuntu 17.04. Could you please provide more info?

Comment: I have solved this issue by cleaning the cloned files however now I am running into some apk not found error... Reinstalling the whole VM.